# Custom Field Suite вывести ссылку картинки

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Custom Field Suite Именно этим плагином нужно вывести картинку и ссылку на картинку. 
При выводе через визуальны редактор оборачивается в тег P. Как этого избежать ?
Как вывести ссылку на картинку? Нужно для применения фоном .
Вот сюда ссылку нужно вывести

style="background-image: url('img/training-exemple.jpg')

Есть вывод всей картинки

```
 <? echo $field['place_img'];?>
```

Этот вывод возвращает такой html-код

```
<p>
    <img src="img.png">
</p>
```

Comment: Вам не нужно echo. Примите поле в строку, и обработайте ее: $str = $field['place_img']; Строковыми операциями выделите из этой строки то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что вам нужно сделать. Поместите в functions.php такой код

```
/**
 * Get string not including the fragment starting with $start and ending with $end.
 *
 * @param $content string String to extract from.
 * @param $start string Start string.
 * @param $end string End string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function outside_str( $content, $start, $end ) {
    $pos1 = mb_strpos( $content, $start );
    if ( false !== $pos1 ) {
        $pos2 = mb_strpos( $content, $end, $pos1 );
        if ( false !== $pos2 ) {
            $content = mb_substr( $content, 0, $pos1 ) . mb_substr( $content, $pos2 + strlen( $end ) );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

А в нужном месте сделайте обработку вашего поля:

```
$str = $field['place_img'];
$url = outside_str( 'src="', '"' );
```

В переменной $url получите ссылку на изображение.

Comment: Не работает... Уже данный вариант пробовал

Comment: Не работает - не ответ. Как именно не работает? Какая ошибка? Код на 146% рабочий, из одного моего проекта.

Comment: Выводит  не то что нужно...

Comment: <?php
                $image =   CFS()->get( 'img-coop' );
                // Берем SRC
                $pattern = '/src="([^"]*)"/';
                preg_match($pattern, $image, $matches);
                $src = $matches[1];
                ?>  Вот так вывело то что нужно

Comment: У вас в вопросе `$field['place_img']`, а в комментарии `CFS()->get( 'img-coop' )`. Вы уж определитесь, что вам нужно. Мне ваш комментарий зачем? У меня мой код работает, то, что вы не смогли его запустить - это уж не ко мне вопрос.